# 80s sci-fi movie about a dude/alien in black space suit in medieval times

Tags: story-identification

I think it might possibly be Italian, but filmed in English.

I remember the guy had a black rubbery spacesuit with a large dome helmet/visor. The suit was organic looking.

He either crashes or visited earth during the medieval ages. I remember him being able to jump high. A knight or king he fought broke his helmet, causing him to have a hard time breathing. I don't think he spoke. I just remember him smiling a lot. He fell in love with some princess or what not.

Answer (score 11):

It might be *[El caballero del dragón](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0088870/)*, aka *Star Knight*. The spacesuit is black, has a dome helmet, and does look sort of organic. The main plotline involves knights trying to battle a "dragon", which turns out to be a spaceship. Unfortunately, I have not actually watched the film, so I cannot confirm that the broken helmet scene happens.

[image: Cover image]

### Trailer

The film has since lapsed into the public domain and can be watched [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IYdAGn4yoNE).

Comment: Bingo!! Yess!! That's the movie! Thank you! Much appreciated.

Comment: :) If you would click the green checkmark to accept the answer, I'd be much obliged. You even get a boost in your user score for doing so.